# What is causing the 'ts(2415)' error when using class factory in TypeScript and how to resolve it?

Tags: typescript

```
class Animal {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  constructor(type: string, name: string) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
  }
  eat() {}
}

interface IClass<T extends Animal> {
    new (...args: any[]): T
}

function classFactory<T extends Animal>(ctor: IClass<T>): IClass<T> {
    class newClass extends ctor {
        constructor(type: string, name: string) {
            super(type, name)
        }

        eat(): void {
            super.eat()
        }
    }
    return newClass as IClass<T>
}
```

The code above can not pass the type check. And the error message is:

```
Class 'newClass' incorrectly extends base class 'T'.
'newClass' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Pass the type check